# Owner drawn tabcontrol has wider tabs

Tags: .net, winforms, tabcontrol, ownerdrawn

I am trying to custom draw a tabcontrol.  When I draw the tabs using the dimensions returned by `GetTabRect`, the tabs are drawn noticeably wider when compared to how they are normally drawn.  I thought it was trying to make room for an image, but I have no images defined for the tabs. Why would `GetTabRect` return a wider size?

Don't know if this has anything to do with it, but here is how I set it to owner draw in the custom TabControl constructor.

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
              ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | 
              ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution here: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2707590/Re-Tab-Size.aspx

**Quote:**

When ControlStyle.UserPaint is set to true, the control no longer sends WM_SETFONT messages.
The code needed to send the FontChange messages:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int WM_SETFONT = 0x30;
private const int WM_FONTCHANGE = 0x1d;

protected override void OnCreateControl()
{
   base.OnCreateControl();
   this.OnFontChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
}

protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnFontChanged(e);
   IntPtr hFont = this.Font.ToHfont();
   SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETFONT, hFont, (IntPtr)(-1));
   SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_FONTCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
   this.UpdateStyles();
}
```

Comment: Eureka! This has been bugging me for a LONG TIME! +1